# Read csv file from website into c++

Tags: c++, sockets

I'd like to read the contents of a .csv file from a website, into a c++ program. Specifically, it is financial data of the form from google finance.

http://www.google.com/finance/historical?cid=22144&startdate=Nov+1%2C+2011&enddate=Nov+14%2C+2011

(If you append "&output=csv" to the above link it will download the data as a csv file)

I know that I can use something like libcurl to download the file and then read it in from there, but I wanted to read it directly into the program without having to write it to a file first.

Can I get some suggestions on the best way to do this? I was thinking boost.asio but I have no experience with it (or network programming in general).

Comment: So... you haven't tried anything yet? Well maybe you should.

Comment: Don't think you cant do this, you need to download a copy first. Just make it a temp file and delete it when you are finished if you do not want it stored.

Comment: I see what you're saying netcoder. Most of the time I come here and my questions have already been asked and answered. I didn't see exactly what I was looking for so I figured I'd ask. I'll look into it further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to download it from a web resource you will need to implement at least some part of the HTTP protocol. `libcurl` will do this for you.

You don't need to save it as a file. [This example](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/getinmemory.html) will show you how to download and store it in a memory buffer.